# Cannot update data from form submission in spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

I'm  a newbie in java and this is my first time using spring framework.
I'd like to update information in database from form submission, but I think the data is not accepted correctly? I'm using MySql and jdbcTemplate, full with model, dao, and service.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap, 
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("post", new Post());
    modelMap.put("post", postService.find(id));
    return "post/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editFormSubmit(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap, 
        @ModelAttribute Post post) {
    postService.update(post);
    return "result/edit_post";
}
```

This is my DAO class

```
@Override
public void update(Post post) {
    String query = "UPDATE post SET questioner=?, answering=?, question=?, "
            + "answer=?, date=?, status=? WHERE id=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, post.getQuestioner(), post.getAnswering(), post.getQuestion(), 
            post.getAnswer(), post.getDate(), post.isStatus(), post.getId());
}
```

This is my model class (if it helps)

```
private int id;
private boolean status;
private String questioner, answering, question, answer, date;

public Post() {
    super();
}

public Post(int id, boolean status, String questioner, String answering, 
        String question, String answer, String date) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.status = status;
    this.questioner = questioner;
    this.answering = answering;
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.date = date;
}

// getters and setters here ...
```

And this is my service

```
@Override
public void update(Post post) {
    this.postDao.update(post);
}
```

Also, this is the edit.html I'm using

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/post/edit/${post.id}}" th:object="${post}" method="post">
ID: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly" /><br/>
Questioner: <input type="text" th:field="*{questioner}" /><br/>
Answering: <input type="text" th:field="*{answering}" /><br/>
Question: <input type="text" th:field="*{question}" /><br/>
Answer: <input type="text" th:field="*{answer}" /><br/>
Date: <input type="text" th:field="*{date}" /><br/>
Status: <input type="number" th:field="*{status}" min="0" max="1" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

The thing is, I dont know where I went wrong. I did exactly the same thing for table user and I can do crud operation and it works perfectly, but when I copied it for table post, I can only do insert and delete, while update only gives error. The error says:

```
HTTP Status 400 - description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Comment: And where is the form/client you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the post and included the form in the question

Comment: Your form submits to `/post/update/` however your controller is mapped for `/post/edit`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I forgot to change it back when I was trying out Avinash suggestion, but even if it's /post/edit it still get the error

Answer (score -1):

Request mapping path cannot be same for more than 2 methods. Use something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap, 
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("post", new Post());
    modelMap.put("post", postService.find(id));
    return "post/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editFormSubmit(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap, 
        @ModelAttribute Post post) {
    postService.update(post);
    return "result/edit_post";
}
```

Comment: @Alvinash I did as you suggested and changed the POST method into update, I also changed the form action in edit.html into `<form action="#" th:action="@{/post/update/${post.id}}" th:object="${post}" method="post">`  but it still returns HTTP Status 400

Comment: The mappings aren't the same... Everything is taken into account, url, method, params etc. for mapping. Indeed the whole combination can exist only once, but you can have perfectly well have 2 methods for the same URL (one GET and one POST).

Comment: I'm afraid I dont understand? I'm using `@Controller @RequestMapping("post")` in the top? So the POST method for `/post/update/${post.id}` is `editFormSubmit` right? I'm using `@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String editFormSubmit()`